# How to save a logit model in R and import it in Python?

Tags: python, r, model, pmml, reticulate

I need to train a glm model in R 3.6 and import it in Python 3.7 to make predictions.

As a proof of concept I borrowed this code from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46523/how-to-simulate-artificial-data-for-logistic-regression/46525

```
set.seed(666)
x1 = rnorm(1000)           # some continuous variables 
x2 = rnorm(1000)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2        # linear combination with a bias
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         # pass through an inv-logit function
y = rbinom(1000,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable
#now feed it to glm:
df = data.frame(y=as.factor(y), x1=x1, x2=x2)
my_model = glm(y~x1+x2, data=df, family=binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

I can save the R model in PMML format, but there is no Python library to import it:

```
library(r2pmml)
r2pmml(my_model, "my_model.pmml")
```

so this is not a solution.

I read that I can export the R model in `pickle` format, but when I try to do this using the `reticulate` library:

```
package.install(reticulate)
library(reticulate)
use_python("/opt/anaconda3/bin/python")
py_save_object(my_model, "my_model")
```

I get this error:

> ```
> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
>       Evaluation error: Evaluation error: Unable to convert R object to Python type..
> ```

Any idea how I can get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Python library [`pypmml`](https://github.com/autodeployai/pypmml) can import PMML file. The example below is based on the R code you provided.

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pypmml import Model                                           
>>> model = Model.fromFile('./Downloads/my_model.pmml')
>>> model.predict({'x1':-0.08629063, 'x2': 2.832245})
{'probability(1)': 0.9999454865350921, 'probability(0)': 5.451346490792375e-05}
```

You may also find [this](https://cmry.github.io/notes/serialize) helpful if you are working specifically with sklearn. Porting the entire R glm model object is difficult, because it contains a long list of things, and among them there are the environment variables (try `str(my_model)` and inspect it yourself). Instead of porting the full model object, you could consider porting just the model coefficients from R - via the use of JSON - and then construct a new model object in Python in the same way as shown in the link.